# Binomial coefficient question?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I'm unsure how to do these types of questions, so any help would be great:

> Find the coefficient of $x^2$ in the expansion of $(x+1/x)^3(x-1/x)^5$

Thanks

Comment: Hint: if negative exponents make you feel less comfortable, just multiply the expression by $x^{3+5}$ and search for the coefficient of $x^{2+8}$. In passing you will see that you can take $x^2$ as new variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On simplification we get $$\frac{(1+x^2)^3}{x^3}\cdot\frac{(1-x^2)^5}{-x^5}$$

$$=-\frac{(1+x^2)^3(1-x^2)^5}{x^8}$$

The coefficient of $x^2$ in  $(x+1/x)^3(x-1/x)^5$

$=-$ the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the [Binomial](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Binomial_Theorem) expansion of $$(1+x^2)^3(1-x^2)^5$$

Now, $$(1+x^2)^3(1-x^2)^5$$
$$=(1+3x^2+3x^4+x^6)(1-\binom51x^2+\binom52(x^2)^2-\binom53(x^2)^3+\binom54(x^2)^4-x^{10})$$
$$=(1+3x^2+3x^4+x^6)(1-5x^2+10x^4-10x^6+5x^8-x^{10})$$

So, the coefficient of $x^{10}$ is $1(-1)+3\cdot5+3(-10)+1\cdot10=\cdots$

Comment: How do you find a coefficient of that equation though?

Comment: I think you misread the OP's exponent $5$ as $-5$, or inserted an extra "/" between the two terms.

Comment: @BarryCipra, thanks for pointing out. Rectified.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, would you please have a look into the edited answer

Comment: @missiledragon, are you OK with the edited answer ?

Comment: Looks OK to me now. One can simplify a bit though before expanding; see the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you advance. Try to simplify the expression as
$$(x+1/x)^3(x-1/x)^5= -\frac{1}{x^8}(1+x^2)^3(1-x^2)^5= -\frac{1}{x^8}(1-x^4)^3(1-x^2)^2$$

$$ = -\frac{1}{x^8}(1-x^2)^2(1-x^4)^3$$

$$ = -\frac{1}{x^8}(1-2x^2+x^4)(1-3x^{4}+3x^8-x^{12})=\dots\,.  $$

Can you finish it now?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may as well simply expand the two binomials.  It's convenient to write the "cubic" from lowest to highest and the "quintic" from highest to lowest, so that we have

$$\left({1\over x}+x \right)^3\left(x-{1\over x} \right)^5=\left({1\over x^3}+{3\over x}+3x+x^3\right)\left(x^5-5x^3+10x-{10\over x}+{5\over x^3}-{1\over x^5} \right)$$

The coefficient for $x^2$ is thus

$$(1\cdot1)-(3\cdot5)+(3\cdot10)-(1\cdot10)=6$$

Answer (score 0):

After applying my hint you are looking for the coefficient of $x^5$ in $(1+x)^3(-1+x)^5$. You can compute this directly, or with a little less effort by recognising $(1+x)(-1+x)=(-1+x^2)$ so that the expression becomes $(-1+x^2)^3(-1+x)^2$ (cf. the answer by Mhenni Benghorbal); computing the coefficient of $x^5$ there is very easy since only the odd exponent in $(-1+x)^2$ contributes, and gives$~-3\times-2=+6$.

Comment: Our answers seem to differ by a minus sign.  I think you meant to look at coefficients in $(1+x)^3(x-1)^5$, not $\ldots(1-x)^5$.

Comment: @BarryCipra: Right, thank you; it's corrected now. I'm just so used to having constant terms equal to $1$ that I did not notice this case was different.